# Why am I not able to send an email from command line

Tags: 11.10, command-line, email, mail

This is what I did (as per a few discussions on this website)

`mail -s "hi" addressee@email.xyz < test.txt`

Where `text.txt` has the message.

I checked to see if mail did exist and it does at `/usr/bin/mail`

What am I missing? Is there a daemon that must be running? Is there more to this?

I am running Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: Might be that you must be in mail group to do that:
`sudo adduser your-user-here mail`

Comment: @Reinis Thanks for your comment. Who exactly is `your-user-here`? The recipient, I am guessing? I'll try it out anyway.

Comment: `your-user-here` is your username you have in your shell! You can see the username you use with before the @ sign in the shell, mine : `marc-andre@T1500:$`

Comment: If you type `id` at the command line it will show you what groups you are in. Please add that to your question. Also what MTA are you using - `postfix` is the default one on ubuntu. If you do `ps -ef | grep postfix` what is the output?

Comment: @HamishDowner Postfix isn't running. So I guess as per the comment below, I should first `sudo apt-get install postfix`

Answer (score 8):

You need to install several packages namely as follows

```
 postfix mailutils libsasl2-2 ca-certificates libsasl2-modules
```

these packages are required for the proper setup of mail sending.
[Here](http://jee-appy.blogspot.com/2016/02/how-to-send-mail-on-ubuntu-or-linux.html) is a proper way of setting this up and testing out by sending mail and the possible troubleshooting.
Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 3):

You will need to install a mail transfer agent.  I would suggest Postfix, since it is widely used and has a good security record:

```
sudo apt-get install postfix
```

You should be asked a few questions about how you want to configure Postfix.  If your ISP requires you to send email via their SMTP server, choose the "Satelite system" option and enter their SMTP server as the relay host.  Otherwise, the "Internet site" option is probably best.

With that set up, the `mail` command line tool should be able to deliver email (along with anything else that relies on the `/usr/lib/sendmail` API).